# php convert array in another format?

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

With the help of php and mysql I am fetching some data from the database. So my code looks like this

```
mysql_connect(_DB_SERVER_,_DB_USER_,_DB_PASSWD_) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(_DB_NAME_) or die(mysql_error());

$sql_listing="SELECT "._DB_PREFIX_."product.id_product,"._DB_PREFIX_."product.id_category_default,description_short,"._DB_PREFIX_."product_lang.name FROM "._DB_PREFIX_."product_lang,"._DB_PREFIX_."product WHERE "._DB_PREFIX_."product_lang.id_lang=1 AND "._DB_PREFIX_."product.id_product="._DB_PREFIX_."product_lang.id_product";

$qry_listing=mysql_query($sql_listing);
```

Now when I did print_r($qry_listing) to check the result array this shows my result like this

```
Array
(
    [description_short] => New design. New features. Now in 8GB and 16GB. iPod nano rocks like never before.
    [name] => iPod Nano
)
Array
(
    [description_short] => iPod shuffle, the world’s most wearable music player, now clips on in more vibrant blue, green, pink, and red.
    [name] => iPod shuffle
)
```

But I want my result should be look like this

```
Array
(
    [iPod Nano] => Array
        (
            [description_short] => New design. New features. Now in 8GB and 16GB. iPod nano rocks like never before.
        )

    [iPod shuffle] => Array
        (

            [description_short] => iPod shuffle, the world’s most wearable music player, now clips on in more vibrant blue, green, pink, and red.
        )

)
```

So can someone kindly tell me how to make my array just like above? any help and suggstions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

```
foreach($qry_listing as $myArr) {
     $newArr[$myArr['name']]['description_short'] = $myArr['description_short'];
}
print_r($newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$result =array();
foreach($array as $arr){
  $result[$arr['name']]['description_short'] = $arr['description_short'];
}
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/110263)